# The famous scroll table problem

Tags: android, android-widget

After recently having to implement a scroll-table in JavaScript (i.e. a table that scrolls but leaves the headers visible so that one can easier visually associate cells with the correct columns) I now seem to bump into this very same problem on Android!

I have a longish TableLayout which I therefore need to put into a ScrollView. I would, however, like the header row of the table to always remain visible. In principle this can be done using two tables (one just containing the header cells and the second containing the body cells and only putting the second table into a ScrollView). However, the issue here starts when the table columns have dynamic widths and adapt to their actual content. One then needs resize-listeners all over the place to keep the column widths of the two tables in sync, so that the headers always properly align with the content columns.

PLEASE tell me that there is already a solution for this out there for Android! I would really hate to have to re-implement this stupid thing AGAIN! 
Any pointers, suggestions or code snippets how to handle this most elegantly on Android?

Michael

Comment: Not that I know of. Headers in scrollviews (including listviews) is a pain in the ass